# Apply @EnableJms conditionally in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

Given the following spring/boot application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = false,
        jsr250Enabled = false)

@EnableJms // we would like to control this from an application property on/off
public class PayZilchCustomerServiceApplication {
    static {
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PayZilchCustomerServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

We are finding that for some local debugging scenarios we want `@EnableJms` turned off. We comment out the line of code. We are occasionally creating PR(s) with the line commented. The PR are being caught by code review.

It's going to slip through one day. How we control `@EnableJms` from an application property file, preferably that it's on by default, but can be turned off with an `application-local.properties` entry.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new class and mark it with these 3 annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "turnonjms", havingValue = "true")
public class MyEnableJmsCustomConfig {
   //you can keep it empty. Just make sure this class
   //is present in the same folder where main class is
}
```

You will pass `turnonjms` property from external sources like runtime args `--turnonjms=true` or `-Dturnonjms`. If it is present, only then `@EnableJms` will be active. Otherwise it will be off.

Or if you like, you can always have JMS enabled and turn it off only when certain external property is present:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "turoffjms", havingValue = "false")
```

If you **don't** pass `turnoffjms` property from external sources, then you will always have JMS enabled. If you pass `--turnoffjms=true`, JMS will be disabled.

On a side note, When you use `@SpringBootApplication`, it already has `@configuration` and `@ComponentScan` annotations within it. You would want to use `@ComponentScan` if you were to scan folders outside of current package. `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(...)` also has embedded `@Configuration`, so it is safe to remove these two annotation from your main class.

Edit:

Since you are already using application-local.properties, insert this entry to turn it off:

`turnoffjms: true` # put `true` in double quotes if it doesn't work